# WYPopoverController on UITabBarController falls

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I create button on UITabBarCOntroller and try to call modal view over all screens in application. I try to use WYPopoverController as a solution
My UITabBarController class is

```
class PlanetTabBarController: UITabBarController, WYPopoverControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBar.tintColor = kTintColor

    var items = self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem]
    let centredTabBar:UITabBarItem = items[2]
    self.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.50

    centredTabBar.image = UIImage()
    self.tabBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    self.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0

    self.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
   // self.tabBar.backgroundImage = ktabBarImage
    self.tabBar.backgroundImage?.imageWithAlignmentRectInsets

    print( UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName)
    if( UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName != "iPhone 6" && UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName != "iPhone 6 Plus"){
       self.tabBar.backgroundImage = ktabBarImage 
    }
    if( UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName == "iPad 2" ){
        self.tabBar.backgroundImage = ktabBarImage
    }



        if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 10) {
            let appearance = UITabBarItem.appearance()
            let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:font]
            appearance.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        }


    let buttonImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "tab_planet")!

    var button: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height)
    button.setBackgroundImage(buttonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    var heightDifference:CGFloat = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height
    if (heightDifference < 0){
        button.center = self.tabBar.center
        button.center.y = self.tabBar.center.y - 5
    }else{
        var center:CGPoint = self.tabBar.center
        center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0 - 5
        button.center = center
    }
    button.addTarget(self, action: "addPlanet:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)






}

func addPlanet(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.showAddPlan()
}

func showAddPlan(){

    var contentViewController =  UIStoryboard(name: "AddPlan", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddPlanController") as? AddPlanController


    var popoverController = WYPopoverController(contentViewController: contentViewController)
    popoverController.delegate = self

    popoverController.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: nil, permittedArrowDirections: WYPopoverArrowDirection.None, animated: false) { () -> Void in
        print ("done")
    }






}

func popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover(popoverController: WYPopoverController!) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

}

But when I try to call my AddPlanController it crashed with error

**An instance 0x7fe4a48849d0 of class Planet.AddPlanController was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:  (
 Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7fe4a4915e00>
**

Please give me an advice how to call something like modal view controller from button on UITabBar, that will be over all screens, with shadow bg. =(

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep reference to `popoverController` until it's visible, but now it deallocated when you return from `showAddPlan` method.

Move definition of `popoverController` from your function and it will work